# unable to install package in R Studio

Tags: r

I am unable to install any package from my R Studio. below errors happen while installing the package.

```
> install.packages("quantmod")
Installing package into '/home/shilab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies 'xts', 'TTR'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xts_0.11-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 537024 bytes (524 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 524 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/TTR_0.23-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 310105 bytes (302 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 302 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/quantmod_0.4-15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 150327 bytes (146 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 146 KB

Error in ptions(error = function() { : could not find function "ptions"
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'xts' had non-zero exit status
Error in ptions(error = function() { : could not find function "ptions"
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'TTR' had non-zero exit status
Error in ptions(error = function() { : could not find function "ptions"
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'quantmod' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/Rtmp7dTsAe/downloaded_packages'
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. What distro are you using?

Comment: R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.I tried to reinstall R 3.6,I had the same problem.